# Javascript Regex to target and remove a css rule from a style tag, based on its selector?

Tags: javascript, css, regex

What would be the regex I could use to completely remove a css rule from an inline stylesheet based on the selector that I provide, via javascript?

For example, I get the contents of the style tag and it contains a rule:

```
.some_class
{
    color: #FFF;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

If i provide the selector '.some_class' what is the correct regex/js method that will find any occurrence of that selector and remove it, its associated brackets, and all the properties/values within those brackets

Comment: please clarify your question. I don't understand what you mean by 'remove it [a selector]'? Do want to remove text from between `<style>` and `</style>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider correctly using the DOM API to achieve what you want, rather than a complex regular expression that may not work very well:

```
function deleteRule(selector) {
    // Get the collection of stylesheets and iterate over them
    var ss = document.styleSheets;

    // Exit if no stylesheets
    if (!ss.length)
        return;

    // Create an uppercase tagname version of our selector for IE
    var uSelector = selector.replace(/^[a-z]+|\s+[a-z]+/gi, function ($0) {
        return $0.toUpperCase();
    });

    // Create a map so we don't get SO's code block scrollbars involved
    var map = {};
    map[selector] = map[uSelector] = 1;

    // `deleteRule` for standards, `removeRule` for IE
    var del = "deleteRule" in ss[0] ? "deleteRule" : "removeRule";

    for (var a = 0, maxA = ss.length; a < maxA; a++) {
        // `cssRules` for standards, `rules` for IE
        var rules = ss[a].cssRules || ss[a].rules;

        for (var b = 0, maxB = rules.length; b < maxB; b++) {
            // Check for selector existence in our map
            if (rules[b].selectorText in map)
                ss[a][del](b);  // remove using our stored delete method
        }
    }
}
```

​
Bear in mind that browsers may reformat the stylesheet rule's selector to include whitespace (so `body>div.selector` becomes `body > div.selector`).  You should try and be as consistent as possible with your whitespace in your CSS selectors.  If you want to delete the rule from a specific stylesheet and not all stylesheets, eliminate the first `for` loop and specify the stylesheet object instead.

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/KE9mm/3)

Comment: Slightly dodgy variable names, but definitely a better option than a (potentially fragile) regex solution.

Comment: @Peter: lol, yeah, they are a bit dodgy.  I don't usually use variations of `i2` in subsequent for loops.

Comment: Yeah this would definitely be a more robust and safer solution for what i am trying to accomplish, thank you :)

Comment: one thing to keep in mind, IE returns element selectors (as well as most property names) capitalized, so if you are looking for a selector with an element base, like p.some_class, you'll need to look for P.some_class as well.

Comment: @kennebec: thanks, I didn't realize IE did that.  It seems all the browsers reformat selectors to include whitespace where necessary. I've updated the post with a solution that will work just as well in IE for those types of selectors.

Answer (score 1):

```
var selector = ".some_class";
var pattern = new RegExp(selector.replace(/\./g, "\\.") + "\\s*{[^}]*?}", "gim");
$("style").html($("style").html().replace(pattern, ""));
```

Comment: If you're using `new RegExp` syntax, I think you need to double escape the \ (so `\\s*`).  
Certainly you need to escape the `.`  - not sure if JS supports the `\Q..\E` syntax, but that's an easy way if it does.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you close - you might need to tweak for specific characters in your css name:value section.

```
.some_class\{([a-zA-Z0-9#]+:[a-zA-Z0-9#]+;\n)*\}
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Ha Ha - Yes I agree with your comments Peter - but as my qualifier states "This should get you close"

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what/why you're doing, but the existing expression is over-complex and looks wrong.

Here's a simple version:

```
^\s*\.some_class\s*\{[^}]*\}
```

Answer (score 0):

This lib may help: https://github.com/Box9/jss

But it's very hard for `@media` or some special classes.

The best way maybe render CSS rules directly from JS:

https://github.com/cssobj/cssobj

This way it's only change rules from js object and it's easier.

The demo: https://cssobj.github.io/cssobj-demo/